# Google Charts API | Axis Number Spacing

Tags: google-visualization

This is my chart:

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxr=0,-20,20&chxs=0,676767,11.5,0.5,l,676767&chxt=y&chbh=23,1&chs=300x150&cht=bvg&chco=C35A21,99877D&chds=-20,20,-20,20&chd=t:-12.8,11,-10.4,-0.7,-0.3|-11.7,13.6,-6.9,0.4,-1.2&chg=20,-1,0,0

You'll notice how 0 is in the middle (which is correct) and that it ranges from -20 to 20 (which is also correct).

I need the number spacing to be in increments of 5 instead of 10. It needs to read
-20 -15 -10 -5 0 5 10 15 20

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? I tried messing with CHXR property and it was adjusting the number spacing but moving the 0 away from the middle and screwing everything up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxr=0,-20,20,5&chxs=0,676767,11.5,0.5,l,676767&chxt=y&chbh=23,1&chs=300x150&cht=bvg&chco=C35A21,99877D&chds=-20,20,-20,20&chd=t:-12.8,11,-10.4,-0.7,-0.3|-11.7,13.6,-6.9,0.4,-1.2&chg=20,-1,0,0

> Axis Range chxr
>
> You can specify the range of values
>   that appear on each axis
>   independently, using the chxr
>   parameter. Note that this does not
>   change the scale of the chart
>   elements, only the scale of the axis
>   labels. If you want to make the axis
>   numbers describe the actual data
>   values, set  and 
>   to the lower and upper values of your
>   data format range, respectively. See
>   Axis Scaling for more information.
>
> You must make an axis visible using
>   the chxt parameter if you want to
>   specify its range.
>
> To specify custom axis values, use the
>   chxl parameter.
>
> Syntax
>
> Separate multiple axis label ranges
>   using the pipe character ( | ).
>
> chxr=
>   ,,,
>       |...|   ,,,
>
> Which axis to apply the labels to. This is a zero-based index into the
>   axis array specified by chxt. For
>   example, the r-axis would be 1 in
>   chxt=x,r,y.  
>       A number, defining the low value for this axis. 
>       A number, defining the high value for this axis. 
>       [Optional] The count step between ticks on the axis. There is no default
>   step value; the step is calculated to
>   try to show a set of nicely spaced
>   labels.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/bar_charts.html#axis_range

Comment: The x axis grid lines have disappeared, other than that this is correct.